# Conditional use of tabbed activity

Tags: android, tabs, launcher

I am trying to create an app that starts with an activity A with a "custom" layout. From that activity it is possible to enter activity B with 3 tabs.

I succeed at creating activity with tabs. The problem is that tabs shows up only if that activity is also launcher activity. If it is not, the tabs do not shows up.

At first time i tried to create tabs with TabLayout. Now i tried to create tabs with TabHost.

Can someone pleas help?

Comment: could you post a code snippet?

Comment: In which part of the code you are interested in?

Answer (score 0):

onCreate method in main activity where tabs are "created".

```
    public class GlavnaStran extends TabActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_glavna_stran);

    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

    TabHost.TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Search");
    TabHost.TabSpec tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Lyric");
    TabHost.TabSpec tab3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Playlist");

    //tab1.setIndicator("Tab1");
    tab1.setIndicator("Search");
    tab1.setContent(new Intent(this, SearchTab.class));

    //tab2.setIndicator("Tab2");
    tab2.setIndicator("Lyric");
    tab2.setContent(new Intent(this, LyricTab.class));

    //tab3.setIndicator("Tab3");
    tab3.setIndicator("Playlist");
    tab3.setContent(new Intent(this, PlaylistTab.class));

    tabHost.addTab(tab1);
    tabHost.addTab(tab2);
    tabHost.addTab(tab3);
}
```

}

For each tab i was created separate activity which looks like that:

```
    public class SearchTab extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_tab);
}
```

}

The xml part of the project is created by importing TabHost container in design view.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="com.example.admin.besedilatakt_v5.GlavnaStran">

<TabHost
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">


            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

In the XML files of tab's activity is nothing special except TextView widget to display some random text.